Hiding a Multi-Select option on D365 Portal form
I am using a d365 portal form to for a customer to create a new case from, however I am unable to hide certain options from a multi-select optionset.
I originally used the information from this link: https://community.dynamics.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=52c125cd-6b01-453b-9b22-ce890bca9e19 - This shows how to hide options from an optionset, however this does not work with the multi-select.

Is anyone able to advise and further?
